# Creating a table in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm looking to recreate the following:

[image: desired outcome]

Could anyone guide me? I've got no clue where to begin.

Comment: The `array` environment has the same syntax as `tabular`.

Comment: To make yourself more familiar to writing  arrays (and matrices too), see introductory text about arrays and matrices. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array, sansmath, upgreek}

\begin{document}

\sansmath
\[ \upgamma_1 = \begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
a & d & c & e & g \\
\hline
a & d & c & e & g
    \end{array}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]